# What is the proper way to close a client in restify?

Tags: node.js, client, restify

I have a restify server receiving a POST then it will reply with a POST call.  I'm using the string client module.  Below is the code:

```
var restify = require('restify');

var client = restify.createStringClient({
   url: 'https://xyz.com'
 });

var postdata = {
  ...
 };

 client.basicAuth('username','pass');

 client.post('/somepath',postdata,
            function(err, req, res, data) {
                if(err) ... else { ... };
                //should the close method be called here??
      });
```

The POST was successful but when I tested it in REPL, it appears the process never terminates. The seems to indicate the connection is still open.  Should the connection be closed in the callback?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restify `StringClient` inherits from `HttpClient`... which has a `close()` method... did you try it?

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Michel.  I tried it and it worked.  I plugged close() in the callback of post method.  I'm curious whether it is the proper place.  What if I make another post call?

Comment: I think it'll not work... on my point of view you should keep the client open as long as you need it (in most of case it should not be a problem...)